# What does 'with context' mean when doing an import?

Tags: salt-stack

I've been looking for an explanation in the SaltStack docs about what 'with context' means. But there's only examples of using context.

What is 'context'?

What does it do here? And why is `Debian` ignored in the `map.jinja` file? (for example `map.log_dir` seems to "jump down" a level)

```
# config.sls
{% from "bind/map.jinja" import map with context %}

include:
  - bind

{{ map.log_dir }}:
  file.directory:
    - user: root
    - group: {{ salt['pillar.get']('bind:config:group', map.group) }}
    - mode: 775
    - require:
      - pkg: bind

# map.jinja
{% set map = salt['grains.filter_by']({
    'Debian': {
        'pkgs': ['bind9', 'bind9utils', 'dnssec-tools'],
        'service': 'bind9',
        'config_source_dir': 'bind/files/debian',
        'zones_source_dir': 'zones',
        'config': '/etc/bind/named.conf',
        'local_config': '/etc/bind/named.conf.local',
        'key_config': '/etc/bind/named.conf.key',
        'options_config': '/etc/bind/named.conf.options',
        'default_config': '/etc/default/bind9',
        'default_zones_config': '/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones',
        'named_directory': '/var/cache/bind/zones',
        'log_dir': '/var/log/bind9',
        'user': 'root',
        'group': 'bind',
        'mode': '644'
    },
    'RedHat': {
        'pkgs': ['bind'],
        'service': 'named',
        'config_source_dir': 'bind/files/redhat',
        'zones_source_dir': 'zones',
        'config': '/etc/named.conf',
        'local_config': '/etc/named.conf.local',
        'default_config': '/etc/sysconfig/named',
        'named_directory': '/var/named/data',
        'log_dir': '/var/log/named',
        'user': 'root',
        'group': 'named',
        'mode': '640'
    },
```

Answer (score 21):

Since this page is the top search result for "jinja import with context" (and the other answer doesn't actually say what it does), and I keep coming back to this page every couple of months when I need to mess with Salt but forget what `with context` does:

When you `import foo` in jinja, normally the macros you've defined in `foo` don't have access to variables in the file you're importing it from. As an optimization, Jinja will then cache this if you import again later in the file. If instead you do `import foo with context`, then the macros in `foo` *can* access the variables in the file it's being imported from. The trade-off is that Jinja no longer caches `foo`, so you pay in render time.

When you do `include`, your variables do get passed into the other file. You then render the contents of the other file and paste them in. If you do `include foo without context`, you don't pass the variables of the current file in. This is useful, because Jinja will optimize this by caching the contents of `foo`, speeding up your render.

Answer (score 3):

`with context` is part of the [jinja template engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).

You can read more about it in the jinja docs:

- [import context
  behavior](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#import-context-behavior)
- [context API](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#the-context)

Regarding the missing debian data - is this your complete map.jinja? the snippet misses `}, default='Debian') %}` according to [grains.filter_by](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.grains.html#salt.modules.grains.filter_by)

Comment: Thanks @dahrens. I still don't understand what context actually is, but I'm guessing it's like variable namespaces. I'm still to reach SaltStack enlightenment... It's just a snipper of map.jinja.

Comment: If you add this `{% set a = 'foo' %}` in the line above the import  you should be able to access the variable `a` from within `map.jinja` as the `context` of your current template gets passed to the import. if you use `without context` instead it will not be available. the context itself is a container for data which can be accessed from within your template.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's standard variable visibility/namespacing.

Comment: Downvote since this doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I downvoted because if I can understand what is write in the manual I have not need to ask on stackoverflow. the example in @dahrens comment  is usefull.